# How can i parse the number in JSON to PYTHON in Intrinio?

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing

I am having trouble parsing the market cap (it is a number) from an API call. I get the data, but for purposes of the program i am developing i just need the number and not the other stuff.

```
import csv
import intrinio
import requests
import json
import re

api_username = "b9cb2b8cbda8dde39f27a21f66e12afd"
api_password = "6d71a6dd01dd554f92a03f0e1b40dd44"

# CSV_URL = 'https://api.intrinio.com/financials/reported.csv?identifier=AAPL&statement=income_statement&fiscal_year=2015&fiscal_period=FY'
# CSV_URL2 = 'https://api.intrinio.com/financials/standardized.csv?identifier=AAPL&statement=balance_sheet&type=FY&fiscal_period=FY&date=2017-05-20'
CSV_URL3 = 'https://api.intrinio.com/data_point?identifier=AAPL&item=marketcap'

with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(CSV_URL3,auth=(api_username, api_password))
    decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')
    cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
    my_list = list(cr)

fx = open(r'test3.csv', 'w')
for item in my_list:
    fx.write("%s\n" % item)

str1 = my_list[0][2]
num = re.findall('\d+', str1)
final_number = float(num[0])
print(final_number)
```

Comment: You imported the `json` module, so did you try using it? Are you getting JSON? What does it look like? If you don't provide that, we can't really help you get that data

Comment: Also, instead of `download.content.decode()`, use `download.json()`, assuming you do get JSON

Comment: JSON doesn't seem to be relevant to what you need here, when I run your code, I get a `list` on this line `my_list = list(cr)`, `[['API_CALL_CREDITS: 1'], ['IDENTIFIER', 'ITEM', 'VALUE'], ['AAPL', 'marketcap', '809247614400.0']]`, which has 3 sub-lists, the number you want to get is the 3rd element in the 3rd sub-list, so try `market_cap_val = my_list[2][2]`, should give `809247614400.0`

Comment: running my_list[2][2] i get IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I was able to get the number. The last issue is the float that is gone. How can i get the 0.0?